# What prevents miners in a pool from retaining the reward?

Tags: mining-pools

From what I understand miners submit their hashes to the pool. What prevents a miner to disengage the pool as soon as she finds the right hash?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What prevents a pool miner from stealing an entire block?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/10687/what-prevents-a-pool-miner-from-stealing-an-entire-block)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The payout address for the miners mined blocks is the pool's moderator address. If the miners are working on blocks with a different payout address (ex. their own), the pool moderator can tell and act accordingly by either banning them or simply ignoring their work.

Answer (score 0):

They have to be mining the entire time on a block template *created by the pool* -- i.e. a block that pays the coinbase transaction to the mining pool and not to themselves.

The hashes they are trying depend on that template, so they can't change the template after they got a good hash, otherwise that would invalidate the block entirely.